# ReactiveX filtering on observable multiple times and merging

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5, reactivex

I have a problem creating the following observable.
I want it to receive a predefined array of values
And I want to filter by different things, and be able to work with these as individual observables.
And then when it comes time to merge these filtered observables, I want to preserve the order from the original one

```
//Not sure the share is necessary, just thought it would tie it all together
const input$ = Observable.from([0,1,0,1]).share();
const ones$ = input$.filter(n => n == 1);
const zeroes$ = input$.filter(n => n == 0);

const zeroesChanged$ = zeroes$.mapTo(2);
const onesChanged$ = ones$.mapTo(3);
const allValues$ = Observable.merge(onesChanged$,zeroesChanged$);

 allValues$.subscribe(n => console.log(n));
//Outputs 3,3,2,2
//Expected output 3,2,3,2
```

EDIT: I am sorry I was not specific enough in my question.
I am using a library called cycleJS, which separates sideeffects into drivers. 
So what I am doing in my cycle is this

```
export function socketCycle({ SOCKETIO }) {
  const serverConnect$ = SOCKETIO.get('connect').map(serverDidConnect);
  const serverDisconnect$ = SOCKETIO.get('disconnect').map(serverDidDisconnect);
  const serverFailedToConnect$ = SOCKETIO.get('connect_failed').map(serverFailedToConnect);
  return { ACTION: Observable.merge(serverConnect$, serverDisconnect$, serverFailedToConnect$) };
}
```

Now my problem arose when I wanted to write a test for it. I tried with the following which worked in the wrong matter(using jest)

```
const inputConnect$ = Observable.from(['connect', 'disconnect', 'connect', 'disconnect']).share();
const expectedOutput$ = Observable.from([
  serverDidConnect(),
  serverDidDisconnect(),
  serverDidConnect(),
  serverDidDisconnect(),
]);
const socketIOMock = {
  get: (evt) => {
    if (evt === 'connect') {
      return inputConnect$.filter(s => s === 'connect');
    } else if (evt === 'disconnect') {
      return inputConnect$.filter(s => s === 'disconnect');
    }
    return Observable.empty();
  },
};
const { ACTION } = socketCycle({ SOCKETIO: socketIOMock });
Observable.zip(ACTION, expectedOutput$).subscribe(
  ([output, expectedOutput]) => { expect(output).toEqual(expectedOutput); },
  (error) => { expect(true).toBe(false) },
  () => { done(); },
);
```

Maybe there is another way I can go about testing it?

Comment: `input$.map(n => n + 2)` and you should look more closely at the output you are expecting.

Comment: If your "work" on each Observable only considers one value at a time, then as @cartant suggests, this should not be viewed as "filtering, working on, then merging" but just straight mapping. In the most general case, your mapping function would direct values to different behaviors with if-else. If they return Observables themselves, you can [concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html) to preserve your order.

Comment: Actually I have separated the map and merge part to another function (taking sources and returning sinks), and it works fine when the inputs come asynchroniously , but when I try to test it, with this where the inputs are specified beforehand it does not preserve order...

Comment: What is this other function doing? If it's not a mapping function, then you'll have to be more specific with what you mean by "preserve order".

Comment: @concat Yeah you are right, I was tired when I put up the question, I have now made a better specification in the edit section.

Comment: You can't say anything about the relative timing of elements between two separate streams even if they come from the same stream. You're seeing the consequences here. Your test could always break regardless because it's relying on timing guarantees that have been broken from splitting up the original stream, and so could your production code.

Comment: @concat Oh well that was what I was afraid of, anyways thanks for the answer. Can you please post it as an actual answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When stream is partitioned, the timing guarantees between elements in different daughter streams is actually destroyed. In particular, even if `connect` events always come before `disconnect` events at the event source, the events of the `connect` Observable won't always come before their corresponding events items in the `disconnect` Observable. At normal timescales, this race condition probably quite rare but dangerous nonetheless, and this test shows the worst case.

The good news is that your function as shown is just a mapper, between events and results from handlers. If you can continue this model generally over event types, then you can even encode the mapping in a plain data structure, which benefits expressiveness:

```
const event_handlers = new Map({
 'connect': serverDidConnect,
 'disconnect': serverDidDisconnect,
 'connect_failed': serverFailedToConnect
});
const ACTION = input$.map(event_handlers.get.bind(event_handlers));
```

**Caveat**: if you were reducing over the daughter streams (or otherwise considering previous values, like with `debounceTime`), the refactor is not so straightforward, and would also depend on a new definition of "preserve order". Much of the time, it would still be feasible to reproduce with `reduce` + a more complicated accumulator.

Answer (score 0):

Below code might be able to give you the desire result, but it's no need to use rxjs to operate array IMHO

```
Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
   Rx.Observable.from([0,0,0]),
   Rx.Observable.from([1,1,1])
).flatMap(value=>Rx.Observable.from(value))
.subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: Sorry but I didn't specifiy clearly enough what I wanted. I have made an edit to the original post with clarification

Comment: the default beheaviour of .from doesn't support async from the test i did with merge but works with zip though 
let a=Rx.Observable.from([1,1,1])
let b=Rx.Observable.from([2,2,2])
Rx.Observable.zip(a,b).subscribe(console.log)